# ¿Como bloqueo una carpeta en especifico de mi servidor usando htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

En mi servidor quiero subir archivos y paginas que solo yo pueda ver.

se que con el...

```
order allow,deny
allow from (IP)
deny from all
```

puedo bloquear a las personas, pero las bloqueo de **todo** el servidor y es lo que quiero evitar.

Como le hago para hacer un `deny from all` pero solo para la carpeta en la que subiré mis paginas? Mientras que el `índex.html` siga publico?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplemente tienes que crear un archivo `.htaccess` en la ruta del directorio que quieres denegar, es decir:

```
/root/directorio_a_denegar/.htaccess
```

El cual debería tener un simple:

```
Deny from all
```

Eso debería bastar para lo que quieres!

Comment: Gracias­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­